# Coding Generating functions

Tags: function, implementation

I was just going through all the Mathematical stuff which is used in programming. There I saw a lot of generating functions which seems to be good in mathematics. But how are they implemented in the form of coding? I mean how these Mathematical functions can be transformed (or thought of as) into code form. As an example, this link shows some generating functions but I don't know how to use/implement those functions in the form of coding. Any striking idea is appreciated.
Thanks.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29

Comment: For starter, maybe you can actually put that link in thw question, otherwise we have no idea what functions you are talking about...

Comment: @Attila sorry i forgot to add the link. I have edited now.

Comment: Have you tried to implement one? What problems did you encounter when doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As an example, this link shows some generating functions but I don't know how to use/implement those functions in the form of coding"
in python they may look like this:
[examples](http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/jkellehe/partitions.php)